# What branch of math studies proving $g(\mathbf x) \leq g(\sigma \cdot \mathbf x)$ results?

Tags: optimization, terminology, convex-analysis, combinatorial-proofs

Let $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \cdots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x_1 \leq \cdots \leq x_n$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. I'm trying to prove a theorem which requires me to prove that my function $g$ has the following property:
$$
g(\mathbf x) \leq g(\sigma \cdot \mathbf x)
$$
where $\sigma \cdot \mathbf x$ denotes a permutation of $\mathbf x$. I was wondering if this property of $g$ falls under any particular math term or branch that I can read about online?

My function $g$ has the following format, if it helps:
$$g(\mathbf x) = \inf_\mathbf y f(\mathbf x, \mathbf y)$$
where $f(\mathbf x, \cdot)$ is convex.

Comment: A *very* long shot, but.. "rearrangement inequalities"?

Comment: Interesting. So what it seems you are proving is that $g$ has a "sorting" property of some sort; that is, it achieves its minimum only when the vector is sorted...

Comment: As a side thought, an example of a function which has such a "sorting property" is the ordered weighted L1 norm (OWL) $\|x\|^w := \sum_{j}w_j x_{(j)}$ restricted to the nonnegative orthant. Here $0 \le w_1 \le w_2 \le \ldots \le  w_n$ are fixed weights.

Answer (score 0):

How about arrangement increasing functions? E.g., http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0047259X88900528